# What are all the possible values for Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button.setIcon and where we can find them?

Tags: autodesk-forge

The [documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/button/#seticon-iconclass) doesn't tell much about the possible values. Searching the GitHub repos, I found a few occurrences
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/button/#seticon-iconclass , but nothing tells more about the values.

I would have opened a GitHub issue about extending the documentation, but I couldn't find the repository for the viewer.

Comment: APS Viewer is a close source project, so there is no GitHub repository for it, unfortunately. But you're welcome to use the `Feedback` button at the right corner of https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/UI/Button/ to send the feedback on the documentation to our documentation team. (it looks required to switch pages on the left navigation bar of the API reference to show the `Feedback` button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article can help you to get the [Icons provided by the viewer stylesheet](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/what-icons-are-provided-viewer-stylesheet).

Then if you want too add custom icon this second article can be useful: [Use custom icons on the Viewer toolbar](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/use-custom-icons-viewer-toolbar).

Also, please note that the link you provided to the viewer documentation refers to the **v2** and we are now in **v7** !

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I got the FontAwesome icons working in my custom toolbar button extension that opens a DockingPanel containing some React components!